# Jquery find and stop if patient not found

Tags: jquery

I am working on a code which has t run in IE only, So for that to work, i am using onPropertyChange Method so as when i type, it should populate immediately.

I have an Issue when there is no Patient or value is coming as 0 or null, it still shows the link. I am trying to stop it somehow, if the value coming from page is 0 or null, either show an alert of just do not write the name of the patient on the screen.

Here is the code which i am trying and having issues, please guide me on this, how can i do it

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#txtPatientLName,#txtPatientFName").bind('propertychange',function() {
        var firstname = document.getElementById('txtPatientFName').value;
        var lastname = document.getElementById('txtPatientLName').value;
        var data = 'firstname='+firstname+'&lastname='+lastname;

        $.ajax({type:"POST",url:"getPatientID.cfm?i=" + Math.random(),
            cache:false,
            data:data,
            success:function(html) {
                $("#txtSelectedPatientID").val(html);
                var k = html;
                $('#url').html('<a id=' + k + 'href=Form.cfm?iform=new&k_patientID=' + k + '>Add Form for ' + firstname + ' ' + lastname + '</a>');
                if (document.getElementById('id').value == '') {
                    alert('Patient Does not Exists');
                    return false;
                };
            }
        });
    });
    $('#url').html('<a href="Form.cfm?iform=new">AddForm</a>');
}); 

 <tr>
        <td colspan="100%" align="center" height="40" valign="middle"><div id="url"></div></td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: Where is your corresponding HTML?

Comment: What element have the id...id ?

Comment: I have added the HTML which is at the end, forgot to add at the time of posting the question